# Network transmission time from the TCP/IP stack

Tags: c++, networking, tcp, network-programming

Every time a client connects to my server I would like to log the transmission time between the client and the server - is there a way of doing this without having to ping the client. My server is written in C++ and listens on a LAN TCP/IP socket. I was hoping that there was something on the TCP/IP stack that I could use once every client connected.

**Update**

Transmission time: Number of milliseconds that it took the client to connect to the server over a computer network like WAN/LAN. Basically the same result that you would get from a running `ping client1.example.com` in a shell.

Comment: Please expand. How do you define "transmission time" ? Are you interested in instantaneous RTT, in total time taken for the connection, etc.

Comment: Which OS do you have ?

Comment: @cnicutar OS portable code, so UNIX, Linux, Windows.

Comment: @cnicutar All are Berkeley sockets compatible though.

Answer (score 1):

There is no completely portable way to find the time the client took to setup the connection, since there is not API to query the kernel for this information. But you have some avenues:

- If you can capture on the interface you can easily measure the time from the first SYN to the ACK. You should be able to do this on most systems.
- On some Unix systems you can enable the SO_DEBUG socket option which might give you this information. In my experience SO_DEBUG is hard to use.

Comment: I _am_ enabling [TCP Keep-alive](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html), I don't know if that changes anything though?

Comment: @IngeHenriksen THat has nothing to do with debugging.

Comment: No, I meant that does TCP Keep-Alive give any additional means of getting the transmission time?

Comment: @IngeHenriksen It doesn't. TCP Keep-Alive is a (controversial) scheme where every few hours or so the hosts send messages to keep middleboxes aware of the connection's existence. There's nothing about it that can help you measure the setup-time.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing explicitly built in to the TCP APIs to do what you want, but assuming you have control over the server and clients, you could do something like:

1. When the client's connect() completes, have the client record the current time (using gettimeofday() or similar)
2. When the server accepts the TCP connection, have it immediately send back some data to the client (doesn't matter what the data is)
3. When the client receives the data from the server, have the client record the current time again, and subtract from it the time recorded in (1)
4. Now you have the TCP round-trip time; divide it by two to get an estimation of the one-way time.

Of course this method will include in the measurement the vagaries of the TCP protocol (e.g. if a TCP packet gets lost on the way from the server to the client, the packet will need to be retransmitted before the client sees it, and that will increase the measured time).  That may be what you want, or if not you could do something similar with UDP packets instead (e.g. have the client send a UDP packet and the server respond, and the client then measures the elapsed time between send() and recv()).  Of course with UDP you'll have to deal with firewalls and NAT blocking the packets going back to the client, etc.